# Grails 2.4.2 - Local class in controller's action

Tags: grails, groovy

Just out of curiosity I tried to place a local class within one of my controller's actions, e.g.:

```
def index() {
    class TestClass {
        TestClass() {
            // do something
        }
        doSomething() { ... }
    }
    TestClass test = new TestClass()
    test.doSomething()
    respond anything
}
```

However, compilation always fails giving me an error like this:

```
Error Compilation error: startup failed: class TestClass ...
                                         ^
```

Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define classes inside methods

Move it outside the method

Comment: I thought it might be possible as groovy is based on Java and I found this here where there is a class within a method: [Java - Local Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) What's the difference?

Comment: Nope, groovy isn't java.  Local classes aren't valid in Groovy...  And to be fair, I've not used them in Java in 16 years of professional Java development...though of course that might be a failing of me

Comment: Ok, thanks! I switched to using an anonymous class :)